# I have some issues with my Andorid project, Error name:#3254133 SIGABRT #01 pc 00000

Tags: weex

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IKMr.png)  This is my error log ,
I can't find the cause of the problem , can u help me?  The app crashed , Will happen by chance.
I am unable to analyze a valid reason from the error log  . Can you help me take a look?